# how to get unit test working?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

how can I get this unit test working?

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/jasonmore').then(function (data) {
            $scope.myData = data;
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );

})
```

and the spec:

```
describe('mocking service http call', function () {
    beforeEach(module('plunker'));

    var myCtrl, $scope;


    describe('with httpBackend', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            $httpBackend.when('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/jasonmore')
                .respond({data:{}});

            myCtrl = $controller('myCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
            $httpBackend.flush();
        }));

        it('should set data ', function () {
            expect($scope.myData).toEqual({data:{}});
        });
    });
});
```

How can I fix this error msg:

```
Expected { data : { data : { } }, status : 200, headers : Function, config : { method : 'GET', transformRequest : [ Function ], transformResponse : [ Function ], url : 'https://api.github.com/users/jasonmore', headers : { Accept : 'application/json, text/plain, */*' } }, statusText : '' } to equal { data : { } }.
```

here is my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/8qu3x9DUTa05fggheclP?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `$http.then` instead of `success` the response contains an object which has properties

data, status, header, config

So the callback assigment is incorrect. It should be:

```
  $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/jasonmore').then(function (data) {
            $scope.myData = data.data;  //this needs to be data.data
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
```